# Win32 C++ How to get current application Service Name

Tags: winapi, service, system

Assuming my code (DLL) already runs inside application that runs as service.
How to find the service name ?
I would like more elegant way than getting process path and enumerating services in registry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using [GetCurrentProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the process ID of the service you're running in.  Then use [EnumServiceStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate the services (without having to use the registry yourself).

You can match the process id from `ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS.ServiceStatusProcess.dwProcessId` to your current process ID and get the name.  For example:

```
void enumerateServices( DWORD processId )
{
    SC_HANDLE hSCM = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, 
        SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);


    if (hSCM == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    DWORD bufferSize = 0;
    DWORD requiredBufferSize = 0;
    DWORD totalServicesCount = 0;
    EnumServicesStatusEx( hSCM, 
        SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO,
        SERVICE_WIN32,
        SERVICE_STATE_ALL,
        nullptr, 
        bufferSize,
        &requiredBufferSize,
        &totalServicesCount,
        nullptr,
        nullptr );

    std::vector<BYTE> buffer( requiredBufferSize );
    EnumServicesStatusEx( hSCM, 
        SC_ENUM_PROCESS_INFO,
        SERVICE_WIN32,
        SERVICE_STATE_ALL,
        buffer.data(), 
        buffer.size(),
        &requiredBufferSize,
        &totalServicesCount,
        nullptr,
        nullptr );

    LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS services = 
        reinterpret_cast<LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS>( buffer.data() );
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < totalServicesCount; ++i )
    {
        ENUM_SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS service = services[i];
        if ( service.ServiceStatusProcess.dwProcessId == processId )
        {
            // This is your service.
            std::wcout << service.lpServiceName << L"PID: " << 
                service.ServiceStatusProcess.dwProcessId << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ( void )CloseServiceHandle( hSCM );

}
```

Usual disclaimers about error handling apply.  I've also not properly checked buffer sizes, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much Steve! Unfortunately my rating does not let me reward you.

Comment: @user1309871 You can mark the answer as accepted if you like the it.  There should be a tick on the left hand side of the answer.